# PDAL issues with python3.5

Tags: pdal

I installed PDAL in Conda Python3.5.6. After manually linked many ".so" files I still got err when I wanted to convert LAS to LAZ file.

```
Unable to open "libpdalpython.pyx": File not found
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem before, it looks like PDAL and python 3.5 have some conflicts. I solved it by:

```
conda create -n py36 python = 3.6
conda install -c conda-forge pdal==1.9.0
conda install -c conda-forge python-pdal
```